# Is there a way to avoid going through all the possible combinations generated by itertools.combinations() in python?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to generate 300 randomized sets/lines of 16 numbers each, from 1 to 64 using Python.

I'm using the itertools package to generate combinations, and this is my code:

```
import itertools
import random


def generate_combinations():
    combinations = list(itertools.combinations(range(1, 64), 16))
    random.shuffle(combinations)
    combinations = combinations[:300]
    return print(*combinations, sep = "\n")
```

Based on my code, the combinations list is generated using the itertools.combinations() function, then those combinations are shuffled and lastly, I limit the list length to 300.

The issue is the time it takes to get the ~488,526,937,079,580 combinations in the first step. Is there any way I can achieve this more efficiently?

Comment: `random.choices` with `k=300`? without shuffle the iterable

Comment: You actually have 366395202809685 combinations not 488526937079580 (because the `range(1, 64)` does not include 64).

Comment: Generate a random combination using `sorted(random.sample(range(1,65), k=16))`. Repeat 300 times - you might want to check for the (very unlikely) event that you get the same combination twice.

Comment: @cards, `random.choices` is `with replacement`. It should be `random.sample`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any approach actually generating all those combos will run out of memory (300 trillion+), but there is a fast way to generate the *nth* combo using an [itertools recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).

```
import math

def nth_combination(iterable, r, index):
    "Equivalent to list(combinations(iterable, r))[index]"
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    c = math.comb(n, r)
    if index < 0:
        index += c
    if index < 0 or index >= c:
        raise IndexError
    result = []
    while r:
        c, n, r = c*r//n, n-1, r-1
        while index >= c:
            index -= c
            c, n = c*(n-r)//n, n-1
        result.append(pool[-1-n])
    return tuple(result)
```

Now you can just generate random indices and get the result:

```
import random

n = 64
r = 16
iterable = range(1, n)
n_combos = math.comb(len(iterable), r)
indices = random.sample(range(n_combos), k=300)  # random.choices if dupes are ok
combos = [nth_combination(iterable, r, i) for i in indices]
```

Comment: I think `sample` also has the advantage that it makes all combinations possible and equally likely, whereas `choices` is biased and can't produce all combinations if the numbers are a bit larger.

Comment: Thank you, this is by far the most efficient and elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have found an alternative to generate the combinations:

```
def combinations():
L = [i for i in range(1, 64)]
total_combinations = []
#noc = number of combinations, in my case 300
for i in range(noc):
    List = random.choices(L, k = 16)
    total_combinations.append(List)
return total_combinations
```

For me, this is fast enough as I go through a finite cycle creating on e combination at a time and appending it top a list I will use later.